# awk - How to print the number of characters for the first n lines in a file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I have a command:

```
$ awk '{ print length($0); }' /etc/passwd
```

It prints number of characters of every line in a **passwd** file:

```
52
52
61
48
81
58
etc.
```

How can I print the number of characters for only the first n lines?

For example - for the first 3 lines it would give something like:

```
52
52
61
```

Comment: @ilkkachu true.

Comment: If you want to ignore blank like then use below - 
`awk '(NR<=line) && length($0) {print length($0)}' line=3 file`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tell `awk` to quit when enough lines have been read:

```
awk '$0 = length; NR==3 { exit }' /etc/passwd
```

Note that this solution ignores empty lines, although not for the line count.

Comment: tricky and cool! (+1)

Comment: If any or the lines is empty, the assignment evaluates to zero (a falsy value), and the length will not be printed.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Depending on the situation, it would be reasonable to ignore empty lines.  I have added a note about this.

Answer (score 14):

A direct Awk version (not so efficient as @Thor's), but slightly more clear:

```
awk 'NR <= 3 {print length}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: If this was `awk '{ print length } NR>=3 { exit }' /etc/passwd`, I'd upvote it.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, thank you. That is a very good suggestion, I will not include it in my answer because it is already implicit in Thor's proposal.

Answer (score 6):

You can execute it with `awk` only command, as nicely described by @Thor, and @JJoao (+1 from me)

You can combine `awk` and `head` with parameter `-n` follows by the number of lines as described below:

Thanks for @Maerlyn suggestion to execute in this order: `head | awk`

e.g. You will get the first 3 lines using:

```
head -n3 /etc/passwd | awk '{ print length($0); }'
```

[head man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/head)

```
-n, --lines=[-]K
    print the first K lines instead of the first 10; with the leading '-', print all but the last K lines of each file
```

Comment: @msjavx86 - great :) please [accept](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)  the answer, when you'll be able to do it

Comment: of course I will - in about 10 minutes ;) thanks again!

Comment: Maybe even reverse, `head -n3 /etc/passwd | awk` so awk doesn't have to process the whole file.

Comment: AWK can count lines, no need for `head`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - thanks for the comment, using `head` was the first working solution which came to my mind. I've upvoted @Thor, @JJoao answer which uses `awk` only solution.